# ERR! code building for production in Vue with npm run build

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, vuejs3

Couldn't find any solution that worked online so asking here, I am a bit of a noob in web development and using npm and such.

Log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.13
3 info using node@v14.17.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle vue-crash@0.1.0~prebuild: vue-crash@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle vue-crash@0.1.0~build: vue-crash@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle vue-crash@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle vue-crash@0.1.0~build: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\D_Documents\Web_dev\vue-crash\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;D:\D_Programs\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\ffmpeg\bin;C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\;C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;D:\D_Programs\MikTeX\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\ffmpeg\bin;C:\Users\peter\AppData\Roaming\Amazon;C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin;C:\Users\peter\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle vue-crash@0.1.0~build: CWD: D:\D_Documents\Web_dev\vue-crash
10 silly lifecycle vue-crash@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'vue-cli-service build' ]
11 silly lifecycle vue-crash@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle vue-crash@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: vue-crash@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:376:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid vue-crash@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd D:\D_Documents\Web_dev\vue-crash
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v14.17.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.13
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error vue-crash@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the vue-crash@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

npm --versions :

```
  npm: '6.14.13',
  ares: '1.17.1',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  cldr: '38.1',
  icu: '68.2',
  llhttp: '2.1.3',
  modules: '83',
  napi: '8',
  nghttp2: '1.42.0',
  node: '14.17.0',
  openssl: '1.1.1k',
  tz: '2020d',
  unicode: '13.0',
  uv: '1.41.0',
  v8: '8.4.371.23-node.63',
  zlib: '1.2.11'
```

Already tried deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and running `npm install`. If you have any idea it would be greatly appreciated since I have no idea where to start.